# How to Connect to EventStore from Service Fabric App on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, eventstoredb

I have created Service fabric (SF) application which interacts with my event store hosted on my local machine, up to here everything is fine.Now I want to move the application to Azure. I have successfully deployed my SF application on Azure and created an Azure Scale Set with 3 nodes and installed EventStore on them.

Now how can I connect my SF application to the hosted EventStore on Azure Scale Set i.e what connection string should I pass in my application parameter file of SF.
I have opened port 2113 and 1113 as well.

Ex. My Public IP to Azure Scale Set : 12.34.567.89

Internal IPs for 3 Nodes are as 11.111.256.4 , 11.111.256.5 and 11.111.256.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your connection string should contain the cluster IP with userid and password.

In your ApplicationParameters .xml file pass the following string :

```
<Parameter Name="EventStoreConnectionString" Value="ConnectTo=discover://userid:password@clusterIP:1113; HeartBeatTimeout=500; MaxReconnections=10000; MaxRetries=100;" />
```

**Note :** Userid & passwords are those configured in EventStore, default values are admin and changeit.

For More details refer to following [link](http://docs.geteventstore.com/dotnet-api/4.0.0/connecting-to-a-server/)